# Kinetic energy confusion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, magnetic-fields, rotational-kinematics, rotation

[image]

If I am travelling horizontally, and suddenly a magnetic force acts on me and pushes me inwards (at 90 degrees), so I will follow a circular motion. But if I take a point in the circle and draw tangent to it, it gives me velocity to the right.

Now suppose that velocity is tilted from horizontal at some angle, and if I resolve it into two components, I would get both vertical and horizontal components, but initially I was travelling horizontally right?

So the force acting at 90 degrees to me would not change my horizontal component of velocity, which means, at that point, my horizontal component is same as my initial velocity but now I have also got a vertical component, so when I add them I get a higher velocity as compared to my initial velocity.

So I have gained kinetic energy, but everyone says that kinetic energy remains same during the circular motion.

Where am I going wrong? Isn’t it true that kinetic energy bumps up in the instant when I start the motion and then remains constant throughout?

From image: Is the magnitude of $v_2$ and $v_1$ the same? If not, why and doesn’t it increase the kinetic energy?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you add diagrams?

Comment: I have added an image, Yashas Samaga, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: $|v_1|$ is not equal to $|v_2|$

Comment: Exactly, so what's changing this component, since magnetic forve acts 90 degrees to it so it can't change it,so what's changing it??

Comment: The magnetic force is changing the component. A perpendicular force can change the direction of velocity but not its magnitude.

Comment: No I am talking about the horizontal components' magnitude, if magnetic force doesn't change the magnitude then wouldn't my horizontals' component magnitude be equal to my initial velocity

Comment: It is not. That is what you've got wrong.

Comment: So now is the real fun part if my new horizontal component is same as my initial component then my new velocity is the vector sum of my initial velocity and a vertical component, which comes to be higher than my initial velocity, means my kinetic energy is greater as compared to my initial situation, so how books say that when you enter a magnetic field, KE remains same??

Comment: No. The new horizontal component is **NOT** equal to your initial horizontal component.

Comment: So then what's changing the magnitude of my horizontal component, I think I  am having a trouble understanding your viewpoint and vice versa

Comment: The magnitude of the horizontal component is changing. The magnetic force changes the direction of the velocity vector. As it is perpendicular, the force cannot change the magnitude of velocity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54796/discussion-between-yashas-samaga-and-sarthak-sharma).

Comment: I am having a trouble understanding you, see if horizontal component is different, then what's changing it???? Magnetic force can't do that, so how is that component changing??

Comment: @SarthakSharma Magnetic forces _can_ change the horizontal component because the direction changes. The force always "tugs" toward the center, $O$. Notice that, at the rightmost point in the circle, the force would pull to the left fully, which is just the _opposite_ of the original velocity direction (to the right)!

Comment: If you have trouble visualizing that the force at the rightmost point pulls to the left, check this diagram. http://imgur.com/DMixeTD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So force acting at 90 degrees to me would not change my horizontal component of velocity means at that point my horizontal component is same as my initial velocity but now I have also got a vertical component, so when I add them I get a higher velocity as compared to my initial velocity.

Here's where you start to go wrong. Let's say the particle is traveling purely in the +x-direction with no velocity in the y-direction. The magnetic field is in the z-direction. So, the force is in the y-direction. In that first instant where the electron feels the magnetic force, it is true that the x-velocity is unaffected and the acceleration is in the y-direction. However, when the particle's velocity changes the force immediately changes. This new force will have a component in the -x direction, reducing the particle's +x-velocity. All of this happens continuously and instantaneously, so the particle's speed doesn't change, just the direction.

If you draw a particle with a velocity not parallel to the x-axis and draw the magnetic force on it, you will see that there is a component of the force acting in the x-direction. So, the x-component of the velocity does change, just not in that first instant.

Comment: Thanks for answering Mark H , so why does this same thing thing doesn't work in projectile motion, doesnt gravity acts same at 90 degress , there we don't see any change in horizontal component

Comment: @SarthakSharma The force of gravity does not change direction as the projectile moves. The magnetic force does. This is also why the force of gravity can do work and change the speed of the projectile. If the motion of the projectile is vertical, then the force of gravity acts in the same direction, not perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

> So force acting at 90 degrees to me would not change my horizontal component of velocity...

This is your incorrect assumption. A force acting at 90 degrees to you does not change your TOTAL velocity. It changes the direction of velocity, essentially rotating your velocity vector. This decreases your horizontal component while increasing your vertical component in such a way that the resultant/hypoteneuse remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering, as you say that total velocity is being changed by magnetic force, it is often good to break that vector into components, so if the force is acting at 90 degrees at all points, how can horizontal component even change? For example. Horizontal component doesn't change in projectile motion so why does it change here!

Comment: In the case of projectile motion, gravity only acts at 90 degrees to the projectile's velocity if this velocity is purely horizontal. But in general, during the projectile's flight, its velocity is on some angle, while gravity is always down. So gravity is not acting at 90 degrees to velocity in projectile motion.

Comment: I am asking if you start with purely horizontal velocity then how can gravity alter your horizontal component, I think it can't and we gain a vertical velocity and our KE increases, so now in magnetic fields, they also acts at 90 degrees if my initial velocity is purely perpendicular to the field, so how it can change the magnitude of my horizontal velocity and if it can't doesn't that mean the KE increases??????

Comment: True, gravity won't change the horizontal velocity of a projectile, near the surface of the Earth. But consider gravity's effect on the Moon. The Moon certainly does not drift horizontally away, so gravity must be changing its horizontal velocity. This is more similar to your magnetic field example because the velocity and force vectors are perpendicular. In the case of projectile motion at the surface, even if you start purely horizontal, once you gain a vertical velocity, your vectors are no longer perpendicular, whereas the magnetic Lorentz force ALWAYS acts perpendicular to velocity.

Comment: I got it finally, thanks so I am thinking like this when we start horizontally we gain some vertical velocity and then our velocity vector starts to rotate now when I resolve that vector there my horizontal component is not perpendicular to field so it changes right!?? But still wouldn't the KE if the particle change by an infinitely small amount when it just enters the field

Answer (score 0):

> See if I am travelling horizontally, and suddenly a magnetic force acts on me and pushes me in wards ( at 90 degrees ), so I will follow a circular motion, but now if I take a point in the circle and draw tangent to it, it gives me velocity right.

You have to give the angle between the magnetic field and the incoming particle.

It is only perpendicular incidence that will create  a circle. If there is an angle it is only the  perpendicular to the magnetic field component that will give a circle. The rest of the momentum creates a helical path and the momentum in the direction along the magnetic field should be added. See [here for bubble chamber paths.](http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/370/bubble.pdf)

Your mistake enters in thinking that the particle can suddenly change the angle with respect to the field . It has that angle all the way through,andthat is what creates the helix, which projected to the perpendicular plane to the magnetic field will give a circle with the velocity component in the horizontal (perpendicular to B plaen)

Now suppose that velocity is tilted from horizontal at some angle, now if I resolve it into two components I would get both vertical and horizontal components, now initially I was travelling horizontally right?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am not talking about helical paths, see take gravity if you throw a ball horizontally with 10m/s, then gravity pulls it down and gives it some vertical component , now horizontal component is still the same and vertical component comes into play too so total velocity will increase and kinetic energy will also increase, now gravity pulls at 90 degrees right so how KE change is described here?? Where am I wrong ???

Comment: The extra energy in the gravity problem comes form the conversion of gravitational potential to kinetic energy. You explicitly are talking of "magnetic force" Did you mean attractive ? Magnetic forces behave as I describe

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic force acting on a charged particle can never change the kinetic energy of the particle because whenever a particle enters a UNIFORM magnetic field, the component of magnetic field along the velocity won't exert any force and the component perpendicular to the velocity can only change the direction of the particle but not it's speed.

$\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$

$|\vec{F}|=q|\vec{v}|\times|\vec{B}|\sin{\theta}$

⁡
As you can see, any component of the uniform magnetic field parallel to (or along) the velocity, cannot exert any force because $\theta=0^{\circ}$ or $\sin{0^{\circ}}=0$

And the component of the magnetic field perpendicular to the velocity can exert force as $\sin{90^{\circ}}=1$, but the work done by this force will be zero because $\cos{90^{\circ}}=0$ Therefore, this force cannot alter the particle's kinetic energy.

$W=|\vec{F}||\vec{d}|\cos{90^{\circ}}=0$